# C++ Find biggest element in an array with negative values

Tags: c++

I set the variable `biggest` to 0 and then looped every element in the array and checked if it is bigger than the current `biggest` value and it works with regular numbers but not with negative ones.
How can I fix it to work with negatives too?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a[7] = { -1, -3, -4, -5, -6, -1, -7 }; //array
    int biggest = 0; //biggest number in the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //looping every element in the array 
        if(a[i] > biggest) { //checking if the current number is bigger then the biiger number
            biggest = a[i]; //setting the biggest number to be = to the current number
         }
     }
     cout << biggest << endl; //printing the biggest number
}
```

Comment: It prints zero right? zero is bigger than all your numbers and you initialize with zero the value biggest so the statement a[i]>biggest never evaluates to true

Comment: The for loop doesn't contain the right array bounds, you're looking up to 3 where your array contains 7 elements.

Comment: Additionally what @SpyrosMourelatos said - 0 is bigger than -7.

Comment: Include `limits` and use `int biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();` Always initialize a variable looking for a maximum with the minimum possible value and vice-versa when looking for a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the initial `biggest` as the first element of the array. You don't need to use any limits.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int a[7] = { -1, -3, -4, -5, -6, -1, -7 };
   int biggest = a[0];
   for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){ 
      if (a[i] > biggest){
         biggest = a[i];
      }
   }
   cout << biggest << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INT_MIN` as it has the minimum value in `int`, you can use this by adding a `#include<climits>` library in your program

Answer (score -1):

It will print the zero but if you want to get the biggest number from your array

initialize your `int biggest = INT_MIN;` instead of `int biggest = 0;`

The value of `INT_MIN`  is `-2147483647 - 1` which will solve your problem.

Also include `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` for `INT_MIN`.

Comment: I do not think that including bits/stdc++.h is a good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/13156261